# Error when deploying .war file to a tomcat server container created on a docker-server ec2 machine by Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

Jenkins installed on an Amazon Linux ec2 machine.
Docker installed on another Amazon Linux ec2 machine.
I created a job with maven to build .war file, and use Publish over SSH plugin to copy the .war file to a tomcat container created by the docker server.

```
1-Send files or execute commands over SSH.
SSH Server Name: docker-server
Source files: webapp/target/*.war
Remove prefix: webapp/target 
Remote directory: //opt//docker 
Exec command: 
docker stop tomcat-server;
docker rm -f tomcat-server;
docker image rm -f tomcat-server;
cd /opt/docker;
docker build -t tomcat-server

2-Send files or execute commands over SSH
SSH Server Name: docker-server 
Exec command: docker run -d name tomcat-server -p 8090:8080 tomcat-server

I got an error when executing the job:
SSH: Connecting from host [ip-172-31-3-34.us-west-1.compute.internal]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [docker-server]
SSH: EXEC: completed after 200 
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [docker-server] 
**ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]**
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
SSH: Connecting from host [ip-172-31-3-34.us-west-1.compute.internal]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [docker-server]
SSH: EXEC: completed after 1,202 
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [docker-server] 
**ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [125]]
Finished: UNSTABLE**
```

Comment: I wanted to know how to solve this error:  Exception when publishing, exception message [Exec exit status not zero. Status [1]]